# JS: Function called after first time results in null error

Tags: javascript

I was just playing around and went to CNN article and ran this code in the console.  The idea was to be able to click a `p` element and it would replace the DOM node with a node that has the reverse text in it.  It works as expected but only once.  When I try to run it again to reverse it back, I am hit with the error in console and I can't tell why:

```
TaggedEventTracker.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
    at e.findNearestZjsOrAElement (TaggedEventTracker.js:56)
    at e.findNearestZjsOrAElement (TaggedEventTracker.js:63)
    at e.trackTaggedEvent (TaggedEventTracker.js:73)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (TaggedEventTracker.js:17)
```

CODE:

```
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(para => {
   para.onclick = function(evt) {
       updateText(evt.target)
   }
})


function updateText(target) {

     let node = target;

     let nodeText = target.innerHTML;

     let newEl = document.createElement('p');
     
     newEl.innerHTML = [...nodeText].reverse().join("");
     node.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, node);
}
```

Comment: well there is no dataset in that code so..... where is the error actually coming from?

Comment: When you replace the node you are probably removing any data attributes that they had for tracking click events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating a new node to replace the old one? You can just replace the innerHTML of the original element.

When you replace the element, it looks like their event tracker got broken.

Also, by replacing the node, you also replace the event handler associated with it.

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(para => {
   para.onclick = function(evt) {
       updateText(evt.target)
   }
})


function updateText(target) {
     target.innerHTML = [...target.innerHTML].reverse().join("");
}
```

```html
<p>`123456789</p>
<p>`123456789</p>
<p>`123456789</p>
```

If you want to keep the original functionality and still replace the text, you will want to clone the node and attach a new event handler.

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(para => {
   para.onclick = function(evt) {
       updateText(evt.target)
   }
})


function updateText(target) {

     let node = target;

     let nodeText = target.innerHTML;

     let newEl = target.cloneNode();
     
     newEl.innerHTML = [...nodeText].reverse().join("");
     node.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, node);
     
    newEl.onclick = function(evt) {updateText(evt.target)}
}
```

```html
<p>12233</p>
<p>x3332233</p>
```

Comment: I know I can manipulate the existing node for that use case.  I am just trying to practice replacing nodes

Comment: @hortenzz1, their website probably has data attributes on the paragraph tags for event tracking. When you replace the nodes with your own, those tracking attributes aren't copied over.

Comment: ohh that would make a lot of sense! Looks like you mentioned that within your answer so I will choose this as solving the question.  Thank you

Comment: @hortenzz1, I also just realized something else. When you replace a node, you are removing the event handlers that were associated with the original.

Comment: @hortenzz1 I know you accepted my answer, but I added a bunch more information for you plus I was able to most likely solve the problem itself with the replacing of the node.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need if you want to swap text in it. Instead of using innerHTML use textContent.

```
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach(para => {
   para.onclick = function(evt) {
       updateText(evt.target)
   }
})


function updateText(target) {

     let node = target;

     node.textContent =  [...target.textContent].reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: `textContent` carries over spacing and styling with it though which I want to avoid